# Convert List<object> to int

Tags: java

//CODE SNIPPET

```
boolean ShouldContinue1 = true;
List<String> b = new LinkedList();
input.useDelimiter("//s");

  




  while (ShouldContinue1) {

       String key = input.nextLine();

       b.add(key);

       int[] num = new int[(b.size()) / 2];
       int[] denom = new int[(b.size()) / 2];

   if (b_contains_string(key) == 1) {
```

// Problem

```
       for (int i = 0; i < b.size() - 1; i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {

               

                   num[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(b.get(i));
            
           } 
          else if (i % 2 != 0) {

           

        denom[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(b.get(i));
        
      }
    }
  } 
  else {

    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {

      if (i % 2 == 0) {
```

//This line causes error

```
            num[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(b.get(i));
```

//

```
      } 
      else if (i % 2 != 0) {

        

             denom[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(b.get(i));
```

//Ends

```
       }
    }

  }
```

//The error message I get (with specified lines)

//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12 24 21 30"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at line

//

//

Not a duplicate, other posts ineffective in explaining my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: "So im trying to cast List as int" - no you're not, you're trying to cast a list *element* to `Integer`, and that element is a `String`.

Comment: You have String. If you want to convert those to int then you need to convert them. Casting doesn't do any conversion and you can only cast to something the Object already is. eG `Object obj = "hey";` and `(String) obj` would work because the Object already is a String.

Comment: This is why you want to use `List<String> = ...`, to get started. And PLEASE read about Java naming conventions - as is, your code is a pain to read :-)

Comment: Don't use raw types either. Say what your List has. `List<String> b = new LinkedList<>();` or even better, `List<Integer> b = ...;` then you dont' have to cast, you just have to convert your strings to integers when you put them in the list.

Comment: @Gyro Gearless      The list contains both numbers and chars

Comment: Hence I cannot convert them to INT when im adding them to the list

Comment: You need to change this, `List<String> b = new LinkedList();` to `List<String> b = new LinkedList<>();` I'm a bit surprised it compiles. Are you sure you're not just running an old version?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the parseInt method for converting string to integer.

Eg:
num[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt((b.get(i));

Comment: num[i / 2] =Integer.parseInt((b.get(i));   

  results in error "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

Comment: Try changing List b = new LinkedList();  to List<String> b = new LinkedList();

Comment: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

Comment: Add one more if before parsing like if(b.get(i) instance of Number){ num[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt((b.get(i));}

Comment: Incompatible conditional operand types String and Number

Comment: Share the latest code snippet

Comment: Edited the post with the latest update

Answer (score 0):

`List<String> b = new LinkedList();` means that the list `b` can only store strings.

You're then checking `if(b.get(i) instanceof Number){`, which won't work because `b` only contains strings, as it is of type `List<String>`. You're getting a compile time error because the compiler knows that it will always be false, because the `String` and `Number` aren't interchangable like that.

`x instanceof SomeType` is used to see if `x`'s type is castable to `SomeType`. So in your code it is checking if the type of `b.get(i)` is stored as a `Number`. `b.get(i)` will always be a string, and so `b.get(i) instanceof Number` will throw an exception, because regardless of what that string is (whether it is "asdaasd" or "12" or "123asda") it will never be stored as a Number, as the value came from a `List<String>`.

Remove the `instanceof Number` if statements as they are causing the errors you are seeing. If you are just expecting numerical strings (like "12", "41", "123" etc) in `b`, just use the `Integer.parseInt`. If you are expecting a mixture of numeric strings and non-numeric strings (like "12", "aaa", "123aaa"), then please look at this question: [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java) . Despite what you said in your question, it is effective at explaining your problem.

(Editted for clarity/based off comment below)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work,  error: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

Comment: My guess is: I think he's trying to check if the String only contains numbers with this `instanceof Number` check. He said his List might contain "Strings and Numbers" so I would guess that the List can contains numerical and non-numerical Strings. Why he doesn't simply search [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)  and seems to keep guessing code is beyond me however.

Comment: @SantaClausSatan It is getting quite hard to help you because you aren't putting much effort into your question or responses. Please could you edit your question to include expected data (ie. what the contents of `b` is likely to be), a well-formatted version of your code, as well as compilation errors (highlighting the specific lines that are causing the errors).

Comment: EXAMPLE: The string will at one point contain {12, 21, 23, 20) and at another point {12, 24, 21, q}

Comment: I've edited the answer to include more information based on your examples. In future please remember that stackoverflow aren't just free programmers for you, and you should put some effort researching your problem and formatting/phrasing your question to include all relevant details. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask